# How can I upgrade to Lubuntu 14.04.1 withot a PAE kernel?

Tags: kernel, lubuntu, pae

On my Dell Latitude D800 laptop, which has an old Pentium M without PAE support, I was able to successfully install Lubuntu 14.04 from the CD. When I try to upgrade, I get the error:

```
PAE not enabled 

Your system uses a CPU that does not have PAE enabled. Ubuntu only 
supports non-PAE systems up to Ubuntu 12.04. To upgrade to a later 
version of Ubuntu, you must enable PAE (if this is possible) see: 
http://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingPAE
```

I have seen the Communit Wiki page for PAE. The suggestion is to add `forcepae` to the command line options. When I do this, I get the same message. Moreover, `dmesg` does not indicate PAE was ever enabled. Is there anything else I can ry to get Lubuntu to upgrade correctly?

Comment: Did you go to the web site quoted in the error, http://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingPAE

Comment: I did but did not catch the lower part, will try that and update this...